# Execute (or queue) set of tasks simultaneously

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, celery

I have the situation like:

- between 5 and 20 test environments separated to groups by 5 VMs (1 set = 5 VMs usually)
- hundreds of test cases which should be executed simultaneously on 1 VM set.
- celery with 5 workers (each worker for 1 VM item from VM's set: **alpha**, **beta**, **charlie**, **delta**, **echo**)

Test sets can run in different order and use diff. amount of time to execute.
Each worker should execute only one test case without overlapping or concurrency.
Each worker run tasks only from its own queue/consumer.

In previous version I had a solution with multiprocessing and it works fine. But with Celery I can't add all 100 tests cases for all 5VMs from one set, it only starts adding tasks for VM **alpha** and wait until they all finished to start tasks for next VM **beta** and so on.

Now when I've tried to use multiprocessing to create separate threads for each worker I got: *AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children*

Problem is - how to add 100 tests for 5 workers at the same time?

So each worker (from **alpha**, **beta**, ...) will run its own set of 100 test cases simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using task keys based on each consumer, like:

```
app.control.add_consumer(
    queue='alpha',
    exchange = 'local',
    exchange_type = 'direct',
    routing_key   = 'alpha.*',
    destination = ['worker_for_alpha@HOSTNAME'])
```

So now you can send any task to this consumer for separate worker using key and queue name:

```
@app.task(queue='alpha', routing_key = 'alpha.task_for_something')
def any_task(arg_1, arg_2):
    do something with arg_1 and arg_2
```

Now you can scale it to any amount of workers or consumers for single worker. Just make a collection and iter them one by one for multiple workers\consumers.

Another issue can be solved with ***--concurrency*** option of each worker. 
You can set concurrency to 5 to have 5 simultaneously threads on one worker. Or break the task flow on separate threads for each worker with unique key and consumer(queue).